# Vue.js Jest unit test failing with: [vuex] unknown action type & TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')"

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am working on writing my first unit test for a Vue app using Jest and vue-test-utils that checks if the Vuex state is being updated. The app sends an axios get request to an endpoint, that checks if there are any active alerts, then dispatches a Vuex action that then commits the mutation which adds any new alerts to the state. My issue is, I am not sure how to connect all the Vuex mutations and actions with axios to get the test to work.

ApiClient.js (global axios)

```
import axios from "axios";

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
})
```

AlertService.js (using the ApiClient above)

```
import apiClient from './ApiClient'

export default {

    getActiveAlerts() {
        return apiClient.get('/alerts');
    }
}
```

Vuex alert.module.js

```
import AlertsService from '@/services/AlertsService.js'

export const namespaced = true

export const state = {
    type: null,
    message: null,
    dismissible: false,
    countdown: 0,
    activeAlerts: []
}

export const mutations = {
    SUCCESS(state, message) {
        state.type = 'success';
        state.message = message;
        state.dismissible = false;
        state.countdown = 0;
    },
    ERROR(state, message) {
        state.type = 'danger';
        state.message = message;
        state.dismissible = false;
        state.countdown = 0;
    },
    DISMISSIBLE(state, message) {
        state.type = 'success';
        state.message = message;
        state.dismissible = true;
        state.countdown = 5;
    },
    CLEAR(state) {
        state.type = null;
        state.message = null;
        state.dismissible = false;
        state.countdown = 0;
    },
    SET_ACTIVE_ALERTS(state, alerts) {
        state.activeAlerts = alerts;
    }
}

export const actions = {
    success({ commit }, message) {
        commit('SUCCESS', message);
    },
    error({ commit }, message) {
        commit('ERROR', message);
    },
    dismissible({ commit }, message) {
        commit('DISMISSIBLE', message);
    },
    clear({ commit }) {
        commit('CLEAR');
    },
    getActiveAlerts({ commit, dispatch }) {
        return AlertsService.getActiveAlerts()
            .then(response => {
                commit('SET_ACTIVE_ALERTS', response.data)
                dispatch('alert/clear', null, { root: true });
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch('alert/error', 'Unable to get active alerts: ' + error, { root: true });
                throw error
            })
    }
}
```

AlertPanel Vue component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-show="isBusy">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <b-spinner variant="primary" label="Checking for alerts"></b-spinner>
        <span class="ml-2 font-weight-bold text-primary"
          >Checking for alerts...</span
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="alerts.length > 0">
      <b-alert show dismissible>
        <div v-for="alert in alerts" :key="alert.id">
          <h4 class="alert-heading">{{ alert.title }}</h4>
          <p>{{ alert.text }}</p>
        </div>
      </b-alert>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AlertPanel",
  data() {
    return {
      isBusy: true,
      alerts: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getActiveAlerts();
  },
  methods: {
    getActiveAlerts: function() {
      this.isBusy = true;
      this.$store.dispatch("alert/getActiveAlerts").then(
        (response) => {
          this.alerts = response;
          this.isBusy = false;
        },
        () => {
          this.isBusy = false;
        }
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Test file alerts.spec.js

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import AlertPanel from "@/components/layout/AlertPanel.vue";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);
localVue.use(Vuex);

jest.mock("axios");

describe("AlertPanel", () => {
  let alerts;
  let state;
  let mutations;
  let actions;
  let store;

  jest.mock("axios");

  beforeEach(() => {
    alerts = {
      id: "1",
      title: "Mock alert title",
      text: "Mock alert text",
    };

    state = {
      activeAlerts: [],
    };

    mutations = {
      SET_ACTIVE_ALERTS: jest.fn(),
    };

    actions = {
      getActiveAlerts: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
    };

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        alertModule: {
          namespaced: true,
          state,
          actions,
          mutations,
        },
      },
    });
  });

  it('dispatch "getActiveAlerts" action', () => {
    jest.spyOn(AlertPanel.methods, "getActiveAlerts");
    mount(AlertPanel, { store, localVue });
    axios.get.mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({ data: { ...alerts } })
    );
    expect(store.modules.alertModule.actions.getActiveAlerts).toBeCalledWith(
      alerts
    );
  });
});
```

The errors I receive

```
by-file-test-pattern-5 is scheduled
  console.error node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:495
    [vuex] unknown action type: alert/getActiveAlerts

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
    [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')"
    
    found in
    
    ---> <AlertPanel>
           <Root>

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1884
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
        at VueComponent.getActiveAlerts (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\src\components\layout\AlertPanel.vue:35:1)
        at VueComponent.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-mock\build\index.js:866:25)
        at C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-mock\build\index.js:480:41
        at VueComponent.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-mock\build\index.js:489:13)
        at VueComponent.mockConstructor (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-mock\build\index.js:182:19)
        at VueComponent.call (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\src\components\layout\AlertPanel.vue:30:1)
        at invokeWithErrorHandling (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1850:57)
        at callHook (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4207:7)
        at VueComponent._init (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4989:5)
        at new VueComponent (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5134:12)
        at createComponentInstanceForVnode (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3277:10)
        at i (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3108:45)
        at createComponent (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5958:9)
        at createElm (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5905:9)
        at VueComponent.__patch__ (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6455:7)
        at VueComponent._update (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3933:19)
        at VueComponent.call (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4054:10)
        at Watcher.get (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4465:25)
        at new Watcher (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4454:12)
        at mountComponent (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4061:3)
        at VueComponent.$mount (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8392:10)
        at mount (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\@vue\test-utils\dist\vue-test-utils.js:14057:21)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\__tests__\unit\alerts.spec.js:52:5)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (c:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
        at c:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queueRunner.js:43:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (c:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at c:\Users\USER_NAME\source\lcat\PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queueRunner.js:73:41
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

 FAIL  __tests__/unit/alerts.spec.js
  AlertPanel
    × dispatch "getActiveAlerts" action (472ms)

  ● AlertPanel › dispatch "getActiveAlerts" action

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

      33 |             getActiveAlerts: function () {
      34 |                 this.isBusy = true;
    > 35 |                 this.$store.dispatch('alert/getActiveAlerts').then(
         | ^
      36 |                     (response) => {
      37 |                         this.alerts = response;
      38 |                         this.isBusy = false;

      at VueComponent.getActiveAlerts (src/components/layout/AlertPanel.vue:35:1)
      at VueComponent.call (src/components/layout/AlertPanel.vue:30:1)
      at invokeWithErrorHandling (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1850:57)
      at callHook (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4207:7)
      at VueComponent._init (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4989:5)
      at new VueComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5134:12)
      at createComponentInstanceForVnode (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3277:10)
      at i (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3108:45)
      at createComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5958:9)
      at createElm (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5905:9)
      at VueComponent.__patch__ (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6455:7)
      at VueComponent._update (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3933:19)
      at VueComponent.call (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4054:10)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4465:25)
      at new Watcher (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4454:12)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4061:3)
      at VueComponent.$mount (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8392:10)
      at mount (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:14057:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/unit/alerts.spec.js:52:5)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.413s
Ran all test suites matching /c:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\source\\lcat\\MilGears\.Tcat\.WebUI\\__tests__\\unit\\alerts\.spec\.js/i with tests matching "AlertPanel".
```

**EDIT:**
Made the edits to the alerts.spec.js test file as recommended by Estus Flask. Still receiving the errors unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`getActiveAlerts` action cannot be stubbed because actions are always expected to return a promise. It should be mocked to return a promise of undefined:

```
getActiveAlerts: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
```

Also it's  incorrect to initialize mocked store in the scope of `describe` function, this will result in test cross-contamination. This needs to be done in `beforeEach` instead.

Comment: I made some edits to the test file and updated the question, but I am still receiving the same errors unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens here. Probably a store was mocked with something else, and `mount(AlertPanel, { store, localVue })` doesn't override it. It complains that `dispatch` doesn't return a promise while this is expected. Try to debug that `wrapper.vm.$store === store`

Comment: This is the only mocked store I’ve created. Am I at least using the store mock and axios correctly? I feel like I’m close to a solution but I’m drawing a blank lol.